# AngularFireStorage returns undefined URL for every upload

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

So I have set up AngularFire within my Angular 6 webapp, and have been trying to use the AngularFireStorage. I have followed the documentation correctly and have it uploading images as I can see in Firebase that the image is uploaded to the specific place and with the specific filePath I am giving. Here is the code:

```
  uploadFile(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const filePath = `test${this.uid}`;
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
    const dlUrl = task.downloadURL();
    dlUrl.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Whenever I am call `console.log(res)` it returns an undefined value. I have not once received an actual download URL from AngularFireStorage, just always returns `undefined`. I can verify that the correct image is uploaded into the storage bucket, and even if it has the same file name, it overwrites the old one. Just to be as clear as possible here is the `<input>` for the file:

`<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png;capture=camera" (change)="uploadFile($event)">`

I am not sure what could be going wrong here as the image successfully uploads, I get zero errors in the console, but just always an undefined string gets returned. Any and all help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
For anyone still following this post, I ended up just using the `firebase` methods and package and skipped `angularfire2` for the storage features. Here is what I did in place of the `angularfire2/storage` methods.

I made an upload method in a service with a `BehaviorSubject<number>` to pass the percentage onto my component:

```
  percentSubject: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor() { }

  pushUpload(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      const uploadRef = storageRef.child(`uploads/${file.name}`);
      this.uploadTask = uploadRef.put(file);
      this.uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
          this.percentSubject.next((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        },
        (error) => {
          reject(error);
        },
        async () => {
          const u = await this.uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          resolve(u);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

This has worked everytime and passes back the correct `downloadURL` with the `Promise.resolve`. I would still like to hear if anyone can get the AngularFireStorage methods working as I am still confused as to why it returns undefined URLs. Hope this can be of help!

EDIT 2:

So after doing some research and looking through the `angularfire2/storage` module I noticed that it is using deprecated firebase methods that were removed starting with version 5.0.0. Here is the release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

If you go down to the 4.13.0 you will see that `FullMetadata.downloadUrls` and `UploadTaskSnapshot.downloadUrl` have been deprecated in favor of `Reference.getDownloadUrl()`. Looking through the `angularfire2` package I noticed this line:

```
downloadURL: function () { return from(task.then(function (s) { return s.downloadURL; })); }
```

in the `task.js` file and realized it is using the old methods and since I am using firebase version 5.0.1 in my application, the variable has been removed and therefore will return undefined everytime. If that line in the `angularfire2/storage/task.js` file is changed to this:

```
downloadURL: function () { return from(task.then(async function (s) { return await s.ref.getDownloadURL(); })); }
```

It returns the correct URL for the uploaded image using Firebase 5+.

So If you want to use AngularFire2 for Storage ATM, make sure your Firebase version correlates with the AngularFire2 versions. Hope this can clear up anyone elses issues!

Comment: What happens if you make dlUrl a property of the class?

Comment: Still returns `undefined` string after making the `Observable<string>` globally available to the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase 5.0 removed `downloadURL()` from upload task and we've mirrored this change in recent AngularFire releases.

I'd suggest using the rxjs finalize operator + the reference, like so:

```
 task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
```

Comment: TSlint shows an error Type  'UploadTaskSnapshot' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireUploadTask'. and when I try to force assign type, it doesn't allows me as Property 'snapshotChanges' is missing in type 'UploadTaskSnapshot'

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem when using Firebase 4.10.1.
After making a lot of research and not being able to find the problem, what I did was to update my Firebase version to 4.13.1, with this the problem was gone.
Currently I have the following versions of Firebase and Angularfire2:

- "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7"
- "firebase": "^4.13.1"

You could try using these versions, but note that you could get the following warning: The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. In order to solve this you should add the following to the constructor of your app.component.ts:

```
constructor (private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    afs.firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
}
```

Reference for the possible warning: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/726

Comment: So I am currently on firebase version 5.0.1, and the metadata for firestore should have no bearing on the firestorage methods. Thank you for the response though, I appreciate the help!